# Selenium - Issue with download of file

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

**Need:** To download CSV file from website - [Link](https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-event-calendar). I am using Selenium to simulate the browser behavior as the download file is controlled by a Javascript

**Issue:** The download works fine a few times, but throws an error (Access Denied) as per attached image on other times.
[image]

I am unable to figure out, why it works sometimes & on other occasions it issues error, although I do not change anything. Hope the issue faced is clear, await inputs on what might be causing this & if I can do anything to fix it at my end.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-event-calendar";
        String elementId = "CFeventCalendar-download";

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path_to_chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        try {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

            driver.get(url);

            // Find the element with the specified ID
            driver.findElement(By.id(elementId)).click();

            // Add a small delay to let the download start
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            System.out.println("File downloaded successfully!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```